# Trying to compare password history to hashed passwords created by SqlMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlmembershipprovider, asp.net-membership

I am using a SqlMembershipProvider and storing my passwords as hashed.  I am also keeping a history of the (hashed) passwords in another table.  I want to be able to compare the password a user tries to change their password to, to their old passwords and throw an error if it was too recent.  I do not seem to be able to figure out how to use the hashing functions to do this.  Basically what I am looking for is a method like this:

```
public bool PasswordCompare(string plaintextPassword, string salt, string hashedPassword)
{
    //where the salt and hashedPassword are pulled out of the aspnet_Membership table
    //which are automatically generated by the provider
}
```

I hope this is clear, thank you.

Comment: Why not simply put a trigger on the aspnet_Membership table that writes the UserId, Password and the current date and time into another logging table which you would then query for the last five?

Comment: @Thomas are you suggestion storing passwords in plaintext?

Comment: @Wyatt Barnett - Of course not. You can store the hash (and salt) into a log table and compare the current hash and salt against that list.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do, I am storing each hashed password, but how exactly do I compare them?  I can't get a hash to line up with an old password even if I put in the exact same password.

Comment: What I ended up doing was changing the password, then checking it against the history - if it was a duplicate, changed it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post has some good info.  Looks like you have to:

> ...implement your own customized
>   MembershipProvider, record the
>   password history and encrypt the
>   password by your self.

[SQLMembershipProvider: Comparing Hashed Passwords](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/asp-net-security/3363/SQLMembershipProvider-Comparing-Hashed-Passwords)